# Simplify Expression Question

Tags: boolean-algebra

Anyone can tell me if I can simplify this expression more? 
I Simplified this function => $minterm(1,3,4,6,7,9,10,11,12,15)$ to this expression:
$W'X'Z+W'Z'X+WYZ+W'XYZ+WX'Y'Z+WX'YZ'+WXY'Z'$

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

$X' Z + Y Z + W X' Y  + X Y' Z' + W' X Z'$

The table of minterms:

[image]

The original expression:

$F0 = W' X' Y' Z + W' X' Y Z + W' X Y' Z' + W' X Y Z' + W' X Y Z + W X' Y' Z + W X' Y Z' + W X' Y Z + W X Y' Z' + W X Y Z;
$

[Karnaugh-Veitch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) map illustrates how the minterms can be covered by five terms:

[image]

Comment: after couple of rows I got this : $W'X'Z+X'Y'Z+W'XZ'+XY'Z'+WYZ+WX'Y+XYZ$ how you did that?